# Is it possible to convert an image from an external source to a base64 string client side?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to convert an image from an external source to a base64 string using html and the `toDataUrl()` and the `canvas` tag and it does not work.  It throws `Dom Exception 8` a security exception, which I later found that it doesn't allow you to convert these images from an external source.

I have setup a way doing it server-side, but I wanna reduce the load on my server downloading images.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: likely you'll need java client-side or silverlight...unfortunately.  Javascript can't handle much with files.  perhaps HTML5 has a solution but i don't know it.

Comment: can you paste some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the image on the server side then relay it to your client like a proxy. It will be as if it was fetched on your server, then have client-side JS do the conversion. Your server will not do the conversion, but will only act like a bridge to work around the security issue.

Comment: do you have an example of this?  How would I relay my image to the client side?  I know how to base64 encode it on the client side, but how do i get it to the client side in such a way that won't conflict with the restriction on toDataUrl()?  Thanks!

Comment: @anthonypliu Your server acts like a proxy. The browser requests your server to get that external resource. On the server, it "downloads" that external image. Once done, the server replies to your client with the resource that it just downloaded. The DOM restriction does not apply since, from the browser, it's as if the image came from your server. There are a lot of examples of "proxies" online. Check them out first.